# Animated ad transition at certain intervals admob

Tags: android, animation, admob

How is it possible for admob ads to appear disappear by scrolling from the top down and back up again at certain intervals in portrait mode top center?

Best

Jim

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a separate thread that at certain intervals checks the position of the scroll view and based on that toggles the visible attribute of the admob view.

Comment: Any example as I don't come from a programming background.